# SQL Server Date Settings

Tags: sql-server, date

We have recently moved some data from an SQL Database instance to another one in another location.

I seemed to have noticed that there are some facets of our old database instance where the date is passed as String to the SQL server and SQL server is able to parse it properly.  For example, the application would simply pass a string value of "15/01/2010" and the database would immediately recognize it as 5th of January 2010.  Is there a setting in SQL server which I need to turn on or modify cause right now, when I passed the same string value, what happens is that an error is being generated cause it cannot understand the string value passed as a date.

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

but you should only use 'safe' formats when using strings

same formats are YYYYMMDD and yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces). It doesn't matter with these 2 formats what your language settings are

Take a look here: [Setting a standard DateFormat for SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se)

If you need to convert output use cast or convert

```
select convert(varchar(30),getdate(),101)
```

03/08/2010

```
select convert(varchar(30),getdate(),101) +' ' 
 +  convert(varchar(30),getdate(),108)
```

03/08/2010 15:21:32

Comment: I tried to set the date format to dmy and when I execute the following SQL

SELECT GetDate()

Yields: 08/03/2010 11:13:06 AM

and when I try to set the dateformat to mdy and execute the same SQL, the date format is still the same.  The settings doesn't seem to get changed at all.

Is this for a specific database instance or is this good for all database on the server?  I only need to set this on an instance of a database on the server. Thanks.

Comment: The setting is for when converting string to dates

Comment: Read the link SQLMenace pointed you to.  It explains that the default lamguage of the login determines how dates are interpreted.  There is also code to show how you can change the default language.